# Static data in firebase is a bad practice?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building an android app that will use firebase. The app in a nutshell, lets users in a couple small communities order food from nearby restaurants.

Is placing in firebase some static data like the available cities, and restaurants that my app supports, considered a bad practice and if yes why (manual upkeep is not an issue for me, because upkeep is limited)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase is perfectly capable of storing static data. You can easily include it in traditional REST clients (such as any web page) by using a URL like `https://yours.firebaseio.com/cities.json`.

If you reach the limit of your Firebase quota, you might want to consider a cheaper option for storing such static data. For example, you could just as easily put the cities on Firebase Hosting and access it as `https://yours.firebaseapp.com/cities.json`.

It essentially is a bang-for-your-buck choice. Storage in the Firebase Database is likely to be relatively expensive, due to it's realtime nature. Storage in a static hosting solution such as Firebase Hosting is likely to be cheaper when operating at scale. But before you reach a large scale, the difference will be negligable.

Comment: up, @Frank. Have you tried playing with SignalR vs Firebase yet?

Comment: I've used SignalR in the past. Not in recent years though.